# Using grep inside of awk

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a quite untidy CSV-file with `;` as field separator. In field 1 I have a name, and in field 3 OR 4 there are address details, separated by comma, with an unspecified number of entries, mostly including an e-mail-address. So it looks like this:

```
Doe, Jon; Some information ; some more information; di: address details, p: (01234) 56789, F: 252470, info@my-domain.com    
Miller, Mariella; Some information ; di: other address, p: (09876) 54321, mailme@the-millers.com    
Brown, Sam; Other information ; di: other address with no e-mail, p: (09876) 54321
```

I want to extract the e-mail-addresses from the file together with the names. I can get the names with

```
BEGIN {FS = ";"}
/@/ {print $1}
```

I can find the e-mail-addresses with this nice grep:

```
grep -i -o "[A-Z0-9._%+-]\+@[A-Z0-9.-]\+\.[A-Z]\{2,4\}" mylist.csv
```

I would like to have the grep called when there is an `@` in the line, resulting in an output like this:

```
Doe, Jon, info@my-domain.com
Miller, Mariella, mailme@the-millers.com
```

But I have no clue how I can call the grep from the awk.

Comment: `awk` can do literally everything `grep` can. There's little point to using an external tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gawk`:

```
$ gawk -F\; 'match($0, /(\w+@[^@]+.)/, a){print $1", "a[1]}' file
Doe, Jon, info@my-domain.com    
Miller, Mariella, mailme@the-millers.com
```

From the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#String-Functions):

> If regexp contains parentheses, the integer-indexed elements of array
>   are set to contain the portion of string matching the corresponding
>   parenthesized subexpression.

**Explanation**

`match($0, /(\w+@[^@]+.)/, a)` will serve us in *two ways*, **match** function will be *true* only if the *regex* captures a mail address, then we enter the *print* part to show the final result.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk you can do this:

```
awk -F ';' '$NF ~ /@/{sub(/ *$/, "", $NF); sub(/.* /, "", $NF); print $1 ",", $NF}' file

Doe, Jon, info@my-domain.com
Miller, Mariella, mailme@the-millers.com
```